# Does Windows 8 still have Administrator accounts and User accounts?

Tags: windows-8

I’ve installed Windows 8 on a VMWare Fusion virtual machine on my Mac.

I used VMWare’s Easy Install option, which gets you to enter a username and password for what it describes as an administrator account:

[image]

Now that I’ve got Windows 8 up and running, I wanted to do what I did for Windows 7 and previous versions, i.e. set up a regular user account to run as, for security purposes.

However, when I added a user (in PC Settings > Users), I couldn’t see a choice between different types of local user accounts. (There is the new choice between “Microsoft” and “Local” accounts, but I’m not interested in that.)

Is there still such a thing as Administrator vs. regular users in Windows 8?

If so, how can I create a regular user account? Or is that what I’ve already done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is Administration account in Windows8 but it's hidden by default, For Enable it to show in the list of users open **Command Prompt** and execute below command:

> `net user administrator /active:yes`

For disable it (don't show in user list)

> `net user administrator /active:no`

And if you want to know that your Username is **Local Account** or **MS Account** also **Administrator** or **Regular** user go to the **Control Panel > User Account and Family Safety > User Accounts**.

It shown under the left photo.

You can access Control Panel by right-clicking on the Start screen, selecting “All Apps”, and scrolling to the “Windows System” category.

Comment: Okay. How do I get to the Control Panel?

Comment: Left SideBar of win8 (Do you know what i mean ?) -> Search -> Write Control Panel

Comment: “Left SideBar of win8 (Do you know what i mean ?)” - unfortunately I don’t. What is it?

Comment: Ok, No problem. Press **Windows Logo+C** in your PC or Notebook it's open sidebar in windows8 then choose **Search** from it. Maybe you have Mac logo instead of Windows logo. Any way see this photo http://www.question-defense.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/dell-xps-1340-windows-key.gif

Comment: Aha, gotcha — sorry, I was confused because on my VM I’ve only been able to make the Sidebar appear from the right. Gotcha. Is there anyway to get the Control Panel to show up aside from searching for it?

Comment: Aha — when using a mouse, if I right-click on the Start Screen (i.e. the new Windows 8 interface, with the tiles), I get a sidebar slide up from the bottom of the screen, with an “All Apps” icon in it. This takes me to the Apps screen, where I ca scroll right to the “Windows System” category, where Control Panel lives.

Comment: Oh sorry i have Win8 in another PC and it's translated to my language and SideBar in the left! I don't know how they do it !!! Yes you when you find control panel in Search just do right click on it and in below menu click on **Pin to tab** or click on **Open file location** then **drog and drop** control panel shortcut from it to your **Desktop**.

Comment: Aha! Of course, that makes sense. Microsoft are pretty great at internationalisation and localisation. Excellent, thank you.

Comment: Your Welcome :X

Answer (score 3):

> Is there still such a thing as Administrator vs. regular users in Windows 8?

Yes, not sure why you can't create a regular account from this screen, you'd create it from the computer management windows by pressing Win+R and typing compmgmt.msc window once you're booted and logged into the Win8 install.

[image: compmgmt.msc]

Comment: “you'd create it from the compmgmt.msc window” — alrighty. How do I get to that window?

Comment: Gotcha. (Side point: is this seriously how Microsoft expects us to manage this stuff? In 2013?)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite No. Type 'Users' on the start screen, select Settings and press enter. There an 'Add User' option at the bottom. This takes you to a screen to set up with a Microsoft Account but there's an option to set up a local account at the bottom. ( If you had a Windows key, you could type Winkey+W to start off).

Comment: @DavidMarshall: right — that’s what I did originally. It’s just that in that interface, there's no option to decide if the Local Account is regular or administrator.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Yes. It creates a standard user and then you have to go to the old Desktop Control Panel if you want to change it to an Administrator. (If there's a modern way, I've not found it yet). Oh, well.

Comment: @DavidMarshall: gotcha. Yeah I wanted a regular user, so it did what I was looking for — I just couldn’t tell if I *had* created a regular user or not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, windows 8 introduced the new concept called "Microsoft account" and "Local account".

- Microsoft account

Microsoft account is the account of your windows live ID and password. Administrator can login with them and he can also add other Microsoft account to the system, so next time anyone can choose their own MS account to login.

- Local account

**Just like the traditional windows system, it includes administrator account and guest (user) account.** By default you are login as administrator, but you can turn the guest account on in the control panel. Yesterday, i did that and realized the guest account is very limited and almost every program you starts you have to enter administrator account passwords. And I couldn't find a way to configure the guest account privileges yet.

Comment: Yup, I’m aware of “Microsoft” and “Local” accounts (I did mention that in the question). You say “You can turn the guest account on in the control panel”. Do you mean in the “PC Settings” screen? If not, how do I get to the control panel?

Comment: do a search when you point to the top right corner of the screen, search for "control panel" and you'll find the classic control panel appears, which is different from the one called "PC settings" (thats something new in windows 8)

Comment: @Icc: ah, gotcha.